# Docker cross compile for ARM without hard-float

Tags: c, linux, docker, arm, cross-compiling

Trying to cross compile for ARM I came across:
    `dockcross/linux-armv6`
which makes it really easy to use.

The docker image works for the `./configure` scripts and `Makefile`s of projects like:

- http://jemalloc.net/
- http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/

However one of my embedded devices has no hard-float.
Therefore `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` is missing and only `/lib/ld-linux.so.3` is available so I cannot use the compiled program/library for this device.

Is there something I can change about the image or any other docker image which supports compiling (for ARM6) without hard-float?

Searching the interwebs resulted only in some trival examples like:

```
arm-linux-gnu-gcc -o hello hello.c
```

or

```
$CC=arm-linux-gnu-gcc make
```

which does not seem to work for this setup...

Comment: Tool-finding is off topic.

Comment: The tool (docker and especialy the image) already exists. However it does not seem to support soft-float. Maybe I am not using it right, maybe there is another solution...

Comment: you use the gcc flag -msoft-float to disable hardware floating point, if your particular gcc configuration by default assumes -mhard-float

Comment: The issue is that the docker image has only `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` installed and no CC flag can change that. Another image is needed. It is even more complicated if you need to execute complex scripts with an own logic such as  `./configure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soultion I found works for me (in parts):

Using the docker container

```
ev3dev/debian-jessie-cross
```

I was able to compile without `hard-float`.

However you might get other issues, such as a mismatching Glibc version...